# import dmp file into a new install of oracle xe

Tags: database, oracle, import, dmp

I'm trying to import a *.dmp file from the database of a client into a new install of Oracle XE 11.2.0.

I'm new to Oracle DB, I always used MySQL, so I have searched the forum and used the command from cmd

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>imp 'system/root AS SYSDBA' file=c:\export.dmp full=yes log=implog.txt
```

with no luck.
The implog.txt is as follows:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Export file created by EXPORT:V09.02.00 via conventional path
import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
export client uses UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SYSTEM's objects into SYSTEM
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDOTBS1" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home/app/oracl"
"e/oradata/ANA/undotbs01.dbf' SIZE 2000M       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5242880  M"
"AXSIZE 32767M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL "
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" BLOCKSIZE 8192 TEMPFILE  '/home2/oradata"
"/ANA/temp01.dbf' SIZE 2916M       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 655360  MAXSIZE 32767M"
" EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  UNIFORM SIZE 1048576"
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1119:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "INDX" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home/app/oracle/oradata"
"/ANA/indx01.dbf' SIZE 1048576       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1310720  MAXSIZE 327"
"67M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMANENT  NOLOGGING SEGM"
"ENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home/app/oracle/oradata/ANA/indx01.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1119:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "TOOLS" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home/app/oracle/oradat"
"a/ANA/tools01.dbf' SIZE 209715200       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 327680  MAXSIZE "
"32767M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMANENT  NOLOGGING S"
"EGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home/app/oracle/oradata/ANA/tools01.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "USERS" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home/app/oracle/oradat"
"a/ANA/users01.dbf' SIZE 1048576       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1310720  MAXSIZE 3"
"2767M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMANENT  NOLOGGING SE"
"GMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO"
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1119:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "XDB" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home/app/oracle/oradata/"
"ANA/xdb01.dbf' SIZE 209715200       AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 655360  MAXSIZE 3276"
"7M EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMANENT  NOLOGGING SEGME"
"NT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home/app/oracle/oradata/ANA/xdb01.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1119:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "A00" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home2/oradata/A/a00.dbf'"
" SIZE 1048576000       EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMAN"
"ENT  NOLOGGING"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home2/oradata/A/a00.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1119:
"CREATE TABLESPACE "D00" BLOCKSIZE 8192 DATAFILE  '/home2/oradata/A/d00.dbf'"
" SIZE 5000M       EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  AUTOALLOCATE  ONLINE PERMANENT  "
"NOLOGGING"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home2/oradata/A/d00.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE USER "OUTLN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '4A3BA55E08595C81' TEMPORARY TABLE"
"SPACE "TEMP" PASSWORD EXPIRE ACCOUNT LOCK"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE USER "ANONYMOUS" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'anonymous' DEFAULT TABLESPACE"
" "XDB" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" PASSWORD EXPIRE ACCOUNT LOCK"
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 959:
"CREATE USER "A00" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'DB7EF8D464FCEC4D' DEFAULT TABLESPAC"
"E "A00" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 959 encountered
ORA-00959: tablespace 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 959:
"CREATE USER "D00" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '546A075B8012922B' DEFAULT TABLESPAC"
"E "D00" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 959 encountered
ORA-00959: tablespace 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"CREATE ROLE "AQ_USER_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
"REVOKE "AQ_USER_ROLE" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 439:
"CREATE ROLE "GLOBAL_AQ_USER_ROLE" IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY "
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 439 encountered
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Enterprise User Security
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE ROLE "OEM_MONITOR""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "REVOKE "OEM_MONITOR" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE ROLE "HS_ADMIN_ROLE""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "REVOKE "HS_ADMIN_ROLE" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE ROLE "XDBADMIN""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "REVOKE "XDBADMIN" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE ROLE "AUTHENTICATEDUSER""
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "REVOKE "AUTHENTICATEDUSER" FROM SYSTEM"
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "A00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT CREATE SNAPSHOT TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT CREATE TYPE TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT "CONNECT" TO "A00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT "DBA" TO "A00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1917:
 "GRANT "CONNECT" TO "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1917 encountered
ORA-01917: user or role 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1918:
 "ALTER USER "D00" DEFAULT ROLE ALL"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1918 encountered
ORA-01918: user 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1918:
 "ALTER USER "A00" DEFAULT ROLE ALL"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1918 encountered
ORA-01918: user 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1918:
 "ALTER USER "A00" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "TEMP" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "A00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1918 encountered
ORA-01918: user 'A00' does not exist
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1918:
 "ALTER USER "D00" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "TEMP" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "D00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1918 encountered
ORA-01918: user 'D00' does not exist
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "MVIEW$_ADVSEQ_GENERIC" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 4294967295 INCR"
 "EMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "MVIEW$_ADVSEQ_ID" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 4294967295 INCREMENT"
 " BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "LOGMNR_SEQ$" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999"
 "99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 ORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "LOGMNR_UIDS$" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999"
 "999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100 CACHE 20 ORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_FLAVORS_S" MINVALUE -2147483647 MAXVALUE 214748364"
 "7 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_FLAVOR_NAME_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999"
 "999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_REPPROP_KEY" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999"
 "9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT_LOG_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999"
 "9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_REFRESH_TEMPLATES_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999"
 "999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_USER_AUTHORIZATIONS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999"
 "99999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_REFGROUPS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999"
 "9999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_OBJECTS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999"
 "99999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_PARMS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999"
 "999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_USER_PARM_VALUES_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999"
 "99999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_TEMPLATE_SITES_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999"
 "999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_TEMP_OUTPUT_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999"
 "999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_RUNTIME_PARMS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999"
 "99999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "TEMPLATE$_TARGETS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999"
 "9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists:
 "CREATE SEQUENCE "REPCAT$_EXCEPTIONS_S" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999"
 "99999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE"
. importing WMSYS's objects into WMSYS
. importing A00's objects into A00
 "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA= "A00""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered
ORA-01435: user does not exist
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Now what I'm reading is:

-the script removes all privileges to user SYSTEM but even though the import fails, after I execute the import I'm no longer able to log in as SYSTEM

-I'm trying to import the *.dmp on a Windows XP 32bit virtual machine, and I think the export has been created on a Windows Vista machine (don't know x86 or x64), but what I'm not understanding is where in the log says "error in creating database file '/home/app/oracle/oradata/ANA/indx01.dbf'". Here it seems a unix path...

-almost everywhere Oracle says it can't create users/tables/indexes because they already exist.. This is a fresh install, or at least it was when I first tried importing. After the first fail I tried to log in as SYSTEM, couldn't so I deleted Oracle XE and reinstalled from scratch, so I think it's a fresh install. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to recreate SYSTEM privileges without deleting and reinstalling everything?

Thank you in advance for your help

EDIT: just received the export log, I've omitted the tables names:

```
Connected to: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
Export done in UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set

About to export the entire database ...
. exporting tablespace definitions
. exporting profiles
. exporting user definitions
. exporting roles
. exporting resource costs
. exporting rollback segment definitions
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting directory aliases
. exporting context namespaces
. exporting foreign function library names
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions
. exporting system procedural objects and actions
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export SYSTEM's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export OUTLN's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export DBSNMP's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export WMSYS's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export ANONYMOUS's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export A00's tables via Conventional Path ...
. about to export D00's tables via Conventional Path ...

. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting triggers
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting user history table
. exporting default and system auditing options
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully without warnings.
```

Comment: If you haven't already found it, you should look at the [import utility documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1023560), particularly the [import parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1021478) which may help you understand some of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify which tablespaces you need to create, you need to find out which tables and indexes are needed, and then see which tablespaces those are built against. The first thing you need to find out is which schemas (users) you need to recreate. From the export log that looks like `A00`, `D00` or both.

You can get the DDL for the tables and indexes, which will include the tablespaces they are built in - by running `imp` with the `INDEXFILE` parameter, something like:

```
imp 'system/root AS SYSDBA' file=c:\export.dmp full=n rows=n fromuser=A00 touser=A00 indexfile=c:\indexfile.sql
```

This will give you a text file with the DDL for the tables and indexes, but with the table creation commands commented out with `rem`. You can view that file in notepad or some other text editor, and search for all the `TABLESPACE` references. You just need all the distinct values. In your case it may be that all the `A00`-owned objects are in the `A00` tablespace, but you'll need to check.

Once you have that information the you can manually create the tablespace(s) you've identified in your new database with the same name(s). You will also need to create the user you're importing to, and make sure it can create objects; in your original import log you have `quota unlimited` set for `A00` on tablespace `A00`, for example, but also look at the `grant` commands it was attempting.

Once they are built you can run the import again as:

```
imp 'system/root AS SYSDBA' file=c:\export.dmp full=n rows=y fromuser=A00 touser=A00 log=import.log
```

The tables, indexes etc. should then build OK, and the data will be imported into them.

You should read up on the import command and parameters to understand what these examples will do, and to decide if any others are needed to modify how the import behaves, based on what your end goal is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I made it. Sorry for the wait for my response but my boss switched me temporarily on another project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this export is from a Linux machine ? Because the path of the tablespace: '/home/app/oracle/oradata/*' seems incorrect in a Windows machine. You can create first the tablespaces and import the dmp after. Just a thought.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to me also, but when in the office of the client I used his computer to find a way into the db and it clearly was Windows Vista... How do I find the tablespace? I just received an export log from the client, just a second and I will post it in the main question. Thank you

Comment: @Andrea - the client you used to connect to the database may well have been running under Windows - possibly SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, PL/SQL Developer, Toad - but that doesn't tell you anything about where the database server was running, or on what operating system.

Comment: Maybe you can execute the sentence: select * from v$version; In my machine the result contains: 'TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Create Tablespace `TOOLS` manually
- Use `FROM_USER`/`TO_USER` parameters in `imp` to import only this user's schema data.

Importing `SYSTEM` and other tablespaces from Oracle 9 to Oracle 11 will break a lot of system related tables/objects that live in that tablespace.

Comment: @amep - I'd see which tablespaces are actually required and only create those; from the log I'd guess `A00` and/or `D00`, and maybe `INDX` or `XDB`. I'd probably try `FROMUSER`/`TOUSER` and `ROWS=N` to see which tablespace(s) is really needs.

Comment: @Alex Poole: to see which tablespaces are needed I'd have to open the 1.6GB *.dmp file with a text editor, but I tried both notepad, notepad++ and writer, but no-one can open it. can you give an advice on this? how do I identify the user FROMUSER? is there something to recognize the owner of the tablespace?

Comment: @Andrea - you won't be able to read the file anyway, at least easily, as it's in a proprietary format. I'll add an answer suggesting something you can try, but you'll need to know which user(s)'s data you want. From the export log it looks like `A00` and/or `D00`, but you may need to get the client to confirm which. Quite a lot of the 1.6G will be internal data which you don't want to import anyway, as it will already exist in your new DB.

Answer (score -1):

open command prompt (here GLOBAL is username and password)
import 11g files only to 11g DB and 10g files only to 10g.

```
> IMP GLOBAL/GLOBAL
password:global
it will give some error ORA-0107
again it will ask for logon username:GLOBAL
Password:global
Import Data Only (yes/no):no
Import file:EXPDAT.DMP > C:\Downloads\global_tables.dmp (location of dump file)
Enter insert buffer size (minimum is 8192) 30720>  

30720
List contents of import file only (yes/no): no >  

no
Ignore create error due to object existence (yes/no): no >  

no
Import grants (yes/no): yes >  

yes
Import table data (yes/no): yes >  

yes
Import entire export file (yes/no): no >  

yes
```